# Primefaces p:calendar not working under ui:composition

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, composite-component

Iam using primefaces in my project and everything works fine except p:calendar component of Primefaces.The following xhtml file doesn't show up the calendar component.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/Templates/Commons/MainContent.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="main_content"> 
        <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:calendar value="#{controller.data}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </ui:define> 
</ui:composition>
```

However if I remove ui:compisition ,as the following snippet shows,it works fine.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:calendar value="#{controller.data}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:form>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I should know about ui:compisition and p:calendar?

Comment: Did you check with including `MainContent.xhtml` file in second way?

Comment: @QadirHussain Doesn't work either.

Comment: what about posting your stack trace ?

Comment: Can you post your MainContent.xhtml? Are you sure that the path to this template is correct?

Comment: @Multisync Everything is displayed from the template including other Primefaces components except p:calendar component.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. It's just a bit strange that <h:body> is not in the template. As I know primefaces loads resources on the page dynamically. And maybe it doesn't work for p:calendar. I suppose if you put some other exotic components they also won't work. So it's still interesting to see your template

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use this **template** it may helps you

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/Templates/Commons/MainContent.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="main_content">
         <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:calendar value="#{controller.data}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
      </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

follow this structure.

Comment: ,know that every other Primefaces components works fine except p:calendar.I tried as you suggested but can't make p:calendar work.Let me know if it works for you.